# Why code coverage sometimes counts method name or closing bracket?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage

Why these lines like method definitions (line with modifiers, method name, arguments etc) or closing brackets counts **sometimes** into line coverage?

[image: Example1]

In this particular example it is a constructor method, but it's not always like that:

[image: Example2]

Can you explain that?

Comment: It is a constructor so it could be shown slightly different. Are you sure that it happens to method also?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Constructor is always like that, but other methods also sometimes have such line covered. I think that this is exactly the same situation when you use a debugger and it stops on the line which seems to do nothing - like closing bracket. I think that it is connected with byte code somehow.

Comment: It depends on the actual tool used, doesn't it?

Comment: And by the way - just by intuition - it may turn out it's only color highlighting of the output which is different and the actual analysis might be the same. I wouldn't be surprised if that was the case.

Comment: There aren't any "rules" -- whatever the tool does is what the tool does.

Comment: I've used three different tools with same results, IntelliJ, Eclipse and PIT. And the answer below is right. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on what coverage tool you are using, but I've seen some that match your results.

The reason, so far as I can tell, is throw/early-return vs hitting the end of the function.

Note that the only method you have with the closing brace highlighted does not return (anything), instead running off the end of the function and so touching the closing brace (and the stack-popping that probably happens there). Same for the constructor, which does not explicitly return anywhere within the function.

In the other examples, the last highlighted line is where execution leaves the function.

You can test this pretty easily by setting up a method that returns early, and testing only that case while collecting coverage. Test the other (return off the end) case with coverage, and compare the two. Hopefully, the second shows the closing brace highlighted.

For example:

```
public class EarlyReturn {
    public static void whatHappens(final Boolean path) {
        System.out.println("Entering method...");

        if (path == null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must have a path.");
        } else if (path) {
            System.out.println("Exiting early...");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Exiting normally...");
    }
}
```

with:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TestEarlyReturn {
    @Test
    public void testEarly() {
        EarlyReturn.whatHappens(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNormal() {
        EarlyReturn.whatHappens(false);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testThrow() {
        EarlyReturn.whatHappens(null);
    } 
}
```

You haven't mentioned line/branch coverage metrics, but in your example, all cases should have 100% coverage (I would hope). This, of course, still depends on the tool and how it samples. My example should not have 100% line coverage, unless you run both tests together.

Comment: The first example have 80% line coverage 66% method coverage. The red line indicates it hasn't been ran. Apart from that, you are right! Thanks! Btw. I know that it depends on the tool, but it seems that most of them (which I used) behave in the same way.

Comment: @MichalChudy Ah, sorry, wasn't paying attention to the red line. 80/66 are the numbers to expect. So long as nothing is counting the closing brace as a executable in functions that return a value, things seem copacetic.